# Getting "Number stored as text" in ag-grid-react excel export

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to export my table in aggrid into Excel. The amount column is using float dataType. When I export in excel. The cell is correctly formatted as Number, but still the cells shows an error "Number stored as Text" and I would have to manually convert them into number. Can anyone suggest any fix for it.

Comment: Were you able to find any optimal fix for this?

Comment: @Praveen Yes! Can't remember the correct code, but it was something with the format of data displayed on the aggrid table. In my case, the amount was displayed with comma and that's why even was reading it as string.